# Define an in-memory JobRepository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm testing Spring Batch using Spring boot. My need is to define jobs working on an Oracle Database but I don't want to save jobs and steps states inside this DB.
I've read in the documentation I can use a in-memory repository with the MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean.

Then, I've implemented this bean:

```
@Bean
    public JobRepository jobRepository() {
        MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factoryBean = new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(new ResourcelessTransactionManager());
        try {
            JobRepository jobRepository = factoryBean.getObject();
            return jobRepository;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

But when my job starts, the first thing Spring Batch does is to create the table in the Oracle DB and continues to use the Oracle datasource. It's like my JobRepository definition isn't taken account.

What did I miss ?

**EDIT**: I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.3 and Spring Batch 3.0.7

Comment: how does your JobLauncher configuration look like? How are you setting this repository to your jobLauncher

Comment: Thanks! I didn't configure a JobLauncher bean.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With SpringBoot 2.x, the solution is simpler.

You have to extend the `DefaultBatchConfigurer` class like this:

```
@Component
public class NoPersistenceBatchConfigurer extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    }
}
```

Without datasource, the framework automatically switches to use the `MapJobRepository`.

Comment: great! it works with @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class}) in the application class

Comment: The simplest and great answer.

Comment: when I use this, the data that I am supposed to write in DB don't get saved anymore

Answer (score 12):

A few things here:

1. If you have a `DataSource` configured in your `ApplicationContext`, by default Spring Batch will try to use it.
2. In order to not use a `DataSource` when one is available within the `ApplicationContext`, you'll need to create your own `BatchConfigurer`.  You can do that by extending the `DefaultBatchConfigurer`.
3. Don't use the `MapJobRepository` except only for testing purposes.  I has a number of issues (thread safety, etc) and is not recommended for production use.  Use an in memory database like HSQLDB instead (you'll still need to create your own `BatchConfigurer` to do so).

Answer (score 3):

Thank the comment of pvpkiran I've found my problem. It's necessary to define a JobLauncher bean.

Below an example:

```
@Bean
public JobRepository jobRepository() {
    MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factoryBean = new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(new ResourcelessTransactionManager());
    try {
        JobRepository jobRepository = factoryBean.getObject();
        return jobRepository;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

@Bean
public JobLauncher jobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository) {
    SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);

    return jobLauncher;
}
```

Comment: You should let exceptions bubble up, never catch them in harmful noop catch blocks.

Answer (score 0):

If using Spring Boot and @EnableBatchProcessing, you would extend the DefaultBatchConfigurer and override the createJobRepository method. Create a ResourcelessTransactionManager and JobRepository using MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean, the rest of the beans will be auto created by Spring Boot.

```
@Configuration
public class InMemoryBatchContextConfigurer extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {
    @Bean
    private ResourcelessTransactionManager resoucelessTransactionManager() {
        return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
    }

    @Override
    protected JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
        MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factoryBean = new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setTransactionManager(resoucelessTransactionManager());
        return factoryBean.getObject();
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Extend `DefaultBatchConfigurer` class and override `createJobRepository` method just like below.

```
@Configuration
public class InMemoryBatchConfigurer extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {
    @Override
    protected JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
        return new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean().getObject();
    }
}
```