# Auto creation of Spring batch schema with boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am trying to write my first spring batch example with spring boot . I want to create database in mysql as soon as application starts up.

I have following dependencies in my pom

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>io.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>hello-world</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>helloWorld</name>
    <description>Hello World for Spring Batch</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <addResources>true</addResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

and application.properties has following configuration

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/batchjob?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password= abcd1234
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.schema=schema-mysql.sql

spring.batch.initialize-schema=always
```

But when I'm starting application, it is not able to recognize Mysql and in the logs it is printing following line

```
2019-03-10 14:32:01.381  INFO 48560 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: HSQL
```

What am I missing which will enable auto schema creation in mySql ?

Comment: Hi!, Did you  try putting `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create`?

Comment: @MarcoPens Do I need to add any other dependency as well ? Tried to put spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create. Same result.

Comment: Looks like you don't have the schema created... And for spring you have to tell it the at it needs to create the schema, you need to have hibernate in your dependencies, you need this `spring-boot-starter-jpa`, keep in mind that you always have to create the database

Comment: @MarcoPens I have added dependency for jpa as well . But even after that my application is not able to recognize mysql database.

Comment: Sorry... But the problem is other.. I was confused this can be help better https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49550523/java-spring-batch-using-embedded-database-for-metadata-and-a-second-database-for&ved=2ahUKEwjl-M-j7_fgAhWZErkGHTcXCXQQjjgwAHoECAcQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2gK1wakyPanKJns1DCgM66

Comment: remove hsql from your maven dependencies - I guess its there... mysql should be picked up automatically now...

Comment: @kukkuz No there is no dependency for Hsql. I've edit my question with my pom.

Comment: another question - do you have a custom `JobLauncher` bean defined in your config? if yes, then you have to pass the `Datasource` to this bean...

Comment: @kukkuz You may be right but all I want to create the spring batch schema in mySql instead of in memory.  I have disabled job run in application.properties file . spring.batch.job.enabled=false so job will not launch.

Comment: `No there is no dependency for Hsql. I've edit my question with my pom`: in that case, the error "No database type set, using meta data indicating: HSQL" should not happen anymore. Please update the question again. I added an answer, it should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You shoud add this:

1. spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

Answer (score 0):

DDL scripts are in the [`org.springframework.batch.core`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core) package, so your `spring.datasource.schema` should be:

```
spring.datasource.schema=org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql
```

You can even omit this property as it will be detected automatically from your datasource.