# spring batch junit with multiple datasources. spring data jpa unable to save data in-memory database

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch, h2, junit5

My scenario is that batch job should read data from 1 DB (H2) and dump data into another DB (postgres).Hence I have configured multiple datasources

I have written batch job using spring batch 4.2 and Spring boot 2.2.5.RELEASE. Now I need to write testcase for end to end testing.

I have used custom Batch Configurer using ResourcelessTransactionManager to avoid saving of batch table meta data in in-memory and actual database and it's working. However,I am unable to save business data in H2 in-memory database in junit by calling readerRepository.save(randomReader); and same is working if I replace H2 in-memory database with postgres testconatiner in junit.

Sample junit of repository test

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootTest
@Import(LiquibaseConfigReader.class)
class ReaderRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private ReaderRepository readerRepository;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        readerRepository.deleteAll();
    }

    @Test
    void shouldFetchAllRecords() {
        var randomReader = RandomDataGenerator.randomReader();
        assertThat(readerRepository.findAll()).hasSize(0);
        readerRepository.save(randomReader);
        assertThat(readerRepository.findAll()).hasSize(1);
    }
}
```

I am unable to understand why I am able to save data in postgres test container but not in in-memory H2 database **while running Junit Test**.

To save batch table meta-data in in-memory map, i tried below solutions and now batch table meta data is not being saved anywhere in DB.However, I started facing spring data jpa issue in junit as mentioned above.

[Java Spring Batch using embedded database for metadata and a second database for other data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49550523/java-spring-batch-using-embedded-database-for-metadata-and-a-second-database)

[Spring boot + spring batch without DataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39913918/spring-boot-spring-batch-without-datasource)

https://github.com/riversoforion/spring-batch-inmem/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/batch/CustomBatchConfigurer.java

Is it because of ResourcelessTransactionManager? If yes, how could I avoid saving batch table metadata in any database including in-memory.

I have scrolled through multiple questions given here but none is able to save business data in h2 database.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer without your source code. As far as I can understand, you want to have one DB to **read** data from (**H2**) and one to **write** data into (**postgres**).

And you don't want Spring batch to write its meta-data in both databases.

Then you write, that you can't understand why you can't **write** to **H2** - I assume, you only mean the spring batch meta-data here.

So a possible solution may be to alter the `BatchConfigurer`:

```
...
public class CustomBatchConfigurer extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("repoDataSource")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean factoryBean = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDatabaseType(DatabaseType.POSTGRES.getProductName());
        factoryBean.setTablePrefix("TMP_");
        factoryBean.setIsolationLevelForCreate("ISOLATION_REPEATABLE_READ");
        factoryBean.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factoryBean.getObject();
    }
```

Here you autowire in the DataSource `repoDataSource`, then the `createJobRepository()` is overwritten, which the `DefaultBatchConfigurer` uses to create the `JobRepository`. Instead of default `BATCH_` it uses a table prefix `TMP_` and instead of default `ISOLATION_SERIALIZED` transaction isolation level is set to `ISOLATION_REPEATABLE_READ`.

Spring doesn't call any of the `create`-methods in `DefaultBatchConfigurer` directly as bean definitions, so `InitializingBean` `afterPropertiesSet()` and `FactoryBean` `getObject()` have to be called explicitely.

If you really don't want to have Spring Batch do a big part of its job and help batch management with its meta-data, your question is a possible duplicate of [Spring-Batch without persisting metadata to database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25077549/spring-batch-without-persisting-metadata-to-database/25077659) .

Comment: I have updated my question with code. Just to clarify, I am unable to save business data in H2 in-memory database in junit by calling readerRepository.save(randomReader);However, if I am actually running my batch service, it's saving data in same in-memory database.