# Want to configure Job with out DataSource

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I am able to run my Springbatch application when Datasource was configured in my SpringbatchConfiguration class. But i dont want Datasource to be configured. SO i used **ResourcelessTransactionManager**. See below my configuration class. Some one guide me how i can launch Jobs without configuring Datasource as part of Batchjob configurations.

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableAutoConfiguration
//@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class SprintgBatchConfiguration {

    /*@Autowired
    private DBConfiguration dbConfig;*/

    /*@Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager;
    */
    //Tomcat relaated configuration//
    @Bean
    public MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
        MultipartConfigFactory factory = new MultipartConfigFactory();
        factory.setMaxFileSize("124MB");
        factory.setMaxRequestSize("124MB");
        return factory.createMultipartConfig();
    }

    @Bean(name="csvjob")
    public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory,StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,ItemReader<List<CSVPojo>> itemReader,ItemProcessor<List<CSVPojo>,CsvWrapperPojo> itemProcessor,AmqpItemWriter<CsvWrapperPojo> itemWriter){
        Step step=stepBuilderFactory.get("ETL-CSV").<List<CSVPojo>,CsvWrapperPojo>chunk(100)
                .reader(itemReader)
                .processor(itemProcessor)
                .writer(itemWriter)
                .build();



        Job csvJob= jobBuilderFactory.get("ETL").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .start(step).build();

        return csvJob;
    }

    @Bean(name="exceljob")
    public Job jobExcel(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory,StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,ItemReader<List<ExcelPojo>> itemReader,ItemProcessor<List<ExcelPojo>,ExcelWrapperPojo> itemProcessor,AmqpItemWriter<ExcelWrapperPojo> itemWriter){
        Step step=stepBuilderFactory.get("ETL-Excel").<List<ExcelPojo>,ExcelWrapperPojo>chunk(100)
                .reader(itemReader)
                .processor(itemProcessor)
                .writer(itemWriter)
                .build();

        Job ExcelJob= jobBuilderFactory.get("ETL-Excel").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .start(step).build();

        return ExcelJob;
    }

    /*@Override
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource){
        System.out.println("overriden");
    }*/

    /*@Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<CSVPojo> fileItemReader(Resource resource){

        return null;
    }*/
    /*@Bean(name="dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException
    {


        //BasicDataSource  dataSource = new BasicDataSource();

        return dataSource;

    }*/
    @Bean(name="transactionManager")
    public ResourcelessTransactionManager transactionManager() throws SQLException{

        return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();

    }
    /*@Bean(name="transactionManager")
    public DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager() throws SQLException{

        DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager(this.dataSource());
        return transactionManager;

    }*/


    /*@Bean
    public JobRepository jobRepository() throws Exception{
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean factoryBean = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDatabaseType("ORACLE");
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factoryBean.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        factoryBean.setIsolationLevelForCreate("ISOLATION_READ_UNCOMMITTED");
        return factoryBean.getObject();

    }*/

    @Bean
    public JobRepository jobRepository(ResourcelessTransactionManager transactionManager) throws Exception {
        MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean = new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(transactionManager);
        mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        return mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean.getObject();
    }


}
```

But i am getting below exception when i am running Application.

ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fileProcessController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jobLauncher'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataSources'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).

Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Spring Boot is intended for building production grade applications. When it is used to build a Spring Batch application, it requires a data source to persist Spring Batch meta-data (See [BATCH-2704](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2704)).

But you can always use either:

- an embedded datasource supported by Spring Boot (H2, HSQL or Derby) by just adding it to the classpath. This data source will be picked up automatically by Spring Batch
- or provide a custom `BatchConfigurer` and use the `MapJobRepository` (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44243647/5019386))

Hope this helps.