# Configure spring batch without persisting metadata

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I need to to change the spring batch application where I don't need to persist in the spring batch metadata tables, instead I need to use the in memory metadata.
My application is not Spring-Boot application, and I am using java configuration for spring.
Also I need to persist into the application tables so I need to use datasource.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Define an in-memory JobRepository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44238232/define-an-in-memory-jobrepository)

Answer (score 0):

Add in-memory DB to your Gradle project dependencies, for example, h2 :

```
compile 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.194'
```

Batch automatically will store the metadata in h2.