# Spring boot batch to export data using read-only account

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

My requirement is that I need to create a spring boot batch program to export data for m Maria db database. However I have a read-only account and do not want the script to alter the database in anyway.when I run my batch program it tries to update the TASK_SEQ table and errors out as my account does not have update permission.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Batch and Spring Cloud Task use a Job/Task repository to store meta-data while running jobs/tasks. If the db account is read-only, you need to use an in-memory job/task repository.

Here is how to do it for Spring Batch:

- [Define an in-memory JobRepository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44238232/define-an-in-memory-jobrepository).
- [Spring-Batch without persisting metadata to database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25077549/spring-batch-without-persisting-metadata-to-database)

The approach is similar for Spring Cloud Task.